# IPad not changing popover location on rotation of screen

Tags: ipad, popover

I have an app that you can rotate the view landscape or portrait, when you do this a button moves location. I have done this by changing the constraints when rotation changes.

Issue is i have popovers that are shown when you select this button. So user can select button, popover is shown, rotate the screen, button moves but the popover still points to the old location of the button.

i am calling the popover by the following code.

```
    TableViewController = [[TableViewPopover alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewPopover" bundle:nil];
    [TableViewController setDelegate:self];
    TableViewPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:TableViewController];
    [TableViewPopoverController setDelegate:self];

    TableViewPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(TableViewController.view.frame.size.width, TableViewController.view.frame.size.height);


    if ([TableViewPopoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [TableViewPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect popRect = CGRectMake((self.LoginButtonProp.frame.origin.x),
                                    (self.LoginButtonProp.frame.origin.y),
                                    (self.LoginButtonProp.frame.size.width),
                                    (self.LoginButtonProp.frame.size.height));
        [TableViewPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Is there an easy solution to rectify this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to present the `UIPopoverController` again in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`: callback.

Consider the following snippet.

```
typedef void (^PopoverControllerPresentationBlock)(void);

@interface ViewController () <UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, copy) PopoverControllerPresentationBlock popoverControllerPresentationBlock;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)showButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    __block __weak UIButton *button = sender;
    __block __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;

    // Save the presentation action in a block
    self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock = ^(void){
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button convertRect:button.bounds toView:weakSelf.view]
                                                inView:weakSelf.view
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                              animated:YES];
    };

    // invoke the presentation block to show the popover now
    self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock();
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock) {
        // While orientation changed, re-invoke the presentation block
        self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock();
    }
}

#pragma mark UIPopoverViewControllerDelegate

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // Clear the presentation block so the popover won't be re-presented after user really dismiss it
    self.popoverControllerPresentationBlock = nil;
    self.popoverController = nil;
}

@end
```

Hope it helps.